# Dynamically change text color of all items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-theme

I want to change my activity theme dynamically without recreating activity, the only solution I've found is to change items properties (like background, textColor) in place, but I have a `ListView` with number of items, 
I can iterate through all items in `ListView` and change `textColor`, but I think it's kinda an ugly solution.
Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have custom arraylist of object, on that put a private int color

```
class myobject {
    private int color;
    public void setColor(int color) { this.color=color; }
    public int getColor { return color; }
}
```

on your custom ArrayAdapter List in getView() set

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setColor(item.getColor());
//Where item is your MyObject at ArrayList(Position)
```

When you want to change color just, on your onClick button Black

```
onClick() {
    for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++) { arraylist.get(i).setColor(Color.Black); }
    arrayadapter.notifydatachange();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but getView() is already called for visible items, and it can't help changing visible items text color.

Comment: You don't have to call it, you just have to declare your getView as you wish, after that when you'll call notifydatachange(), android will make magic

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this in your Adapters `getView()` method:

```
int theme = getThemeColorFromPrefrences();

if(theme == darkTheme){
   textView.setTextColor(...);
}
else{...}
```

Now every time the user changes the color, you just call `invalidateViews()` on your `ListView`:

```
// set other theme color [...]
myListView.invalidateViews()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own layout for the ListView rows, and that way you can specify the text color on the layout file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have my own custom row layout, my problem is something else! I want to change color of row texts, dynamically. Assume I have two button, Black and White, when i press black/white, I want to change color of all list items to back/white.